# Debate, Bare Plurals, and Mass Nouns

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns, generic

The current high school debate resolution is “Resolved: In the United States criminal justice system, jury nullification ought to be used in the face of perceived injustice.”

Although the resolution doesn’t seem to have a generic bare plural, is it correct to only talk about one kind of injustice? For example, if a debater decided to only focus on racial injustice, would this be a semantically correct interpretation of the topic? Is the word injustice an example of a mass noun?

Comment: Like many abstracts, _injustice_ is normally a mass noun, but can be used as a count noun. In fact I detect two different meanings for a count noun: 1) an instance of injustice; 2) a class or type of injustice.

Comment: @Colin: You seem to be catching John Lawler disease, putting good answers in comments.

Comment: I was aware that I wasn't addressing part of his question, so I didn't write an answer.

Comment: We'd usually use 'a miscarriage of justice' for an instance in the UK.

Answer (score 3):

*Injustice* meaning the state of unfairness is a mass noun:

> Jim Crow was an era of institutionalized **injustice**.

But the word can be particularized to mean an instance of unfariness:

> The decision in *Dred Scott* was **the injustice** that made the American
>   Civil War inevitable.

Both uses may be modified -- racial injustice, social injustice, cruel injustice -- but the debate topic simply says *perceived*.  If you argue that perceived racial injustice is enough for nullification, won't your opponents counter that you haven't made the required point because there are other types of perceived injustice?